# Automatic flags attached to irrelevant posts

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comment-flags, automatic-flags

I'm a moderator on EE.SE. In the past few days, I've seen the system create automatic flags against a particular user ("more than three rude/NC comments ..."). Now, this particular user can be perceived as abrasive at times, and the flag itself is not too surprising. What IS surprising is that the flag is attached to a seemingly random post that this user has no association with that I can find.

What's going on here? Is it a bug?

Comment: Usually, this is attached to the last post they had a flagged and deleted comment on. Do you see any deleted comments on these auto-flagged posts?

Comment: @BradLarson: No, I explicitly checked for that.

Comment: I looked at the flag history and it looks like Monica's right in this case.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, that's annoying. What's happening is that the flag has to be attached to a post, so the system uses the latest post containing a flag-deleted rude comment. Ignore the post and the innocent bystander and click on the link in the flag itself.

I wish these flags could be attached to the commenting user so they'd show up in the list of a user's received flags. But that's harder; what if the user doesn't have any posts? (Yeah, that happens; I've suspended 101-rep users whose only site activity was rude comments.)

Comment: I'm not sure that's a complete explanation. The post in question had no comments on it at all that I could find, deleted or otherwise.

Comment: Oh? That's new. When I've seen it it's always been a I said. Could you double check?

Comment: I'll get back to you on that. I already dismissed the flag, so I need to go figure out how to access the log, which is never simple.

Comment: You can get to the log from the mood dashboard, but then you have to dig.